# Custom view draw circle produces ellipse

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a custom view and I'm trying to draw a circle in the middle of the view. However the code produces an ellipse:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
p.setStrokeWidth(0.02f);

mCanvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.2f, p);
```

[image: problem]

The view width and height is the same as the darker round rectangle.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using any kind of drawable there? Like for the background, or similar?

Comment: No drawables, I'm using a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries, I figured out that it's because the width and height of the canvas were not equal.
I had to scale the canvas to the same width/height.
This is my code if anyone encounters the same problem:

```
mCanvas.save();
mCanvas.scale(1f, RATIO); //ratio between width and height
mCanvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f/RATIO, 0.2f, p);
mCanvas.restore();
```